# How to import large mysql database on wamp server

Tags: mysql, database

Is there an easy way to import a large `.sql` file of my database on local host without using `phpmyadmin`? I am using the `WAMP` server.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to the console you can run mysql directly and just import the file.

something to the effect of:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < sqlfile.sql
```

Comment: How to use a path instead of the file name? for example: c:/wamp/app/file.sql - > doing this always return an erro of syntax.

Comment: @B4NZ41, be ware of the spells and case of the directories and file names, suppose if directory name is "Folder" and you use "folder" it will return error. C:/Folder/upload/myFile.sql

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the limitations of PhpMyAdmin:
http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/comment-page-4/#comment-63552

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have included the pertinent parts from the link provided by titanfold and modified them for what worked in my current case. Thank you to daipratt.co.uk for the [original information](http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/).

Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory.
For example:

```
C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.4\config.inc.php
```

Add the following line in an appropriate place. I added mine after the $cfg['blowfish_secret'] line for example.

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';
```

Create a directory called 'upload' within the phpmyadmin directory.

```
C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.4\upload\
```

Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the new upload directory.

Now when you go onto the import page within phpmyadmin, you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t there before – it contains all of the sql files in the upload directory that you have just created. You can now select this and begin the import.